# Data Conversion while creating table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, error-code

Error while creating table but the SQL is retrieving result

Please find the below code, the below SQL by itself is working fine retrieving results!

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN J.JOBID = DJ.JOBNUMBER
     THEN DJ.JOBID ELSE J.JOBID 
                 END AS JOBID, 
J.DISTRICTID,   
CASE WHEN D.DISTRICTID = J.DISTRICTID 
     THEN D.NAME ELSE NULL 
                 END AS DISTRICT_NAME,
D.SEGMENTID,
CASE WHEN D.SEGMENTID = S.SEGMENTID AND D.DISTRICTID = J.DISTRICTID
     THEN S.NAME ELSE NULL 
                 END AS SEGMENT,
J.STARTTIME, 
J.ENDTIME, 
SJ.COMCATJOBTYPEID, 
J.JOBTYPEID,
CASE WHEN J.JOBTYPEID = JT.JOBTYPEID 
     THEN JT.NAME ELSE NULL 
                 END AS JOBTYPENAME,
TS.SSSEGMENT AS SUBPL_NAME,
CONCAT(D.DISTRICTID,TS.SSSEGMENT) AS DISTRICTSUBPLID
FROM `EAR-AA-242`.JOB J
LEFT JOIN `EAR-AA-242`.DISTRICT D ON J.DISTRICTID = D.DISTRICTID
LEFT JOIN `EAR-AA-242`.DMJOB DJ ON DJ.JOBNUMBER = J.JOBID 
LEFT JOIN `EAR-AA-242`.JOBTYPE JT ON JT.JOBTYPEID = J.JOBTYPEID
LEFT JOIN `EAR-AA-242`.STANDARDJOBTYPE SJ ON JT.STANDARDJOBTYPEID = SJ.STANDARDJOBTYPEID
LEFT JOIN `EAR-AA-239`.TBLJOBTYPE TJ ON SJ.COMCATJOBTYPEID = TJ.JOBTYPEID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SS.SSSEGMENT, SS.NODEID FROM `EAR-AA-239`.TBLSSSEGMENT S, 
                    `EAR-AA-239`.TBLSSSEGMENT SS WHERE S.SSS = SS.PARENTSSS AND SS.DELETED = 0) TS ON TJ.SSSEGMENT =TS.NODEID                    
LEFT JOIN `EAR-AA-242`.SEGMENT S ON S.SEGMENTID = D.SEGMENTID
WHERE DATE(J.STARTTIME) > DATE_SUB(DATE(SYSDATE()), INTERVAL 367 DAY) 
ORDER BY J.JOBID;
```

The same code code , while creating a table is throwing an 
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '11COC0011'

```
CREATE TABLE ODS.JOB_LOCATION_IDISTRICT AS

SELECT 
CASE WHEN J.JOBID = DJ.JOBNUMBER
     THEN DJ.JOBID ELSE J.JOBID 
                 END AS JOBID, 
J.DISTRICTID,   
CASE WHEN D.DISTRICTID = J.DISTRICTID 
     THEN D.NAME ELSE NULL 
                 END AS DISTRICT_NAME,
D.SEGMENTID,
CASE WHEN D.SEGMENTID = S.SEGMENTID AND D.DISTRICTID = J.DISTRICTID
     THEN S.NAME ELSE NULL 
                 END AS SEGMENT,
J.STARTTIME, 
J.ENDTIME, 
SJ.COMCATJOBTYPEID, 
J.JOBTYPEID,
CASE WHEN J.JOBTYPEID = JT.JOBTYPEID 
     THEN JT.NAME ELSE NULL 
                 END AS JOBTYPENAME,
TS.SSSEGMENT AS SUBPL_NAME,
CONCAT(D.DISTRICTID,TS.SSSEGMENT) AS DISTRICTSUBPLID
FROM `EAR-AA-242`.JOB J
LEFT JOIN `EAR-AA-242`.DISTRICT D ON J.DISTRICTID = D.DISTRICTID
LEFT JOIN `EAR-AA-242`.DMJOB DJ ON DJ.JOBNUMBER = J.JOBID 
LEFT JOIN `EAR-AA-242`.JOBTYPE JT ON JT.JOBTYPEID = J.JOBTYPEID
LEFT JOIN `EAR-AA-242`.STANDARDJOBTYPE SJ ON JT.STANDARDJOBTYPEID = SJ.STANDARDJOBTYPEID
LEFT JOIN `EAR-AA-239`.TBLJOBTYPE TJ ON SJ.COMCATJOBTYPEID = TJ.JOBTYPEID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SS.SSSEGMENT, SS.NODEID FROM `EAR-AA-239`.TBLSSSEGMENT S, 
                    `EAR-AA-239`.TBLSSSEGMENT SS WHERE S.SSS = SS.PARENTSSS AND SS.DELETED = 0) TS ON TJ.SSSEGMENT =TS.NODEID                    
LEFT JOIN `EAR-AA-242`.SEGMENT S ON S.SEGMENTID = D.SEGMENTID
WHERE DATE(J.STARTTIME) > DATE_SUB(DATE(SYSDATE()), INTERVAL 367 DAY) 
ORDER BY J.JOBID;
```

Any help absolutely appreciated!!!

Comment: If you ran your select query in mysql-workbench, I guess only the first rows are actually read. But when you run it with the ```CREATE TABLE```, all the rows are read at once then the error is thrown. If you scroll down in the workbench results until the end, you should finally also throw the error

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the datatypes of the columns explicitly. Without that, MySQL has to figure out what the types are. When you're using a `CASE` expression to return the values for a column, it assumes that the column datatype will be the same as the type of the first `THEN` value, but this will be wrong if other cases return a different type. In your code, you have some `CASE` expressions where the first result is `DOUBLE`, but another result is a `CHAR` string that can't be converted to `DOUBLE`.

So it should be

```
CREATE TABLE ODS.JOB_LOCATION_IDISTRICT (
    JOBID VARCHAR(30),
    DISTRICTID INT,
    ...
) AS
SELECT 
...
```

Comment: I tried it but still the same error, not sure why
CREATE TABLE ODS.JOB_LOCATION_IDISTRICT 
(
 JOBID varchar(100),
 DISTRICTID int(10),
 DISTRICT_NAME varchar(200),
 SEGMENTID int(10),
 SEGMENT varchar(200),
 STARTTIME datetime, 
 ENDTIME datetime, 
 COMCATJOBTYPEID int(10), 
 JOBTYPEID int(10),
 JOBTYPENAME varchar(300),
 SUBPL_NAME varchar(200),
 DISTRICTSUBPLID varchar(300)
 )  
SELECT 
CASE WHEN J.JOBID = DJ.JOBNUMBER
     THEN DJ.JOBID ELSE J.JOBID 
                 END AS JOBID, 
J.DISTRICTID,......